capacitor ionic vue input type=file multifle?
Given this line of code:
<ion-input type="file" multiple class="img_input" ref="fileInput" 
    @change="handleFileChange" v-model="contractFile"></ion-input>

If you click on the input box above in the capacitor app, it will be saved as a recent file in the app. However, when you go into the external app gallery and select one item, it does not hit the change event. When you select multiple items, it will hit the change event well.
When adding an external app file, the handle File Change function does not run.
